# create new role?

Tags: postgresql

I'm a newbie to PostgreSQL.

I'm trying to create a new role named `pgdba` like below...

```
localhost.localdomain:[/home/postgres]createuser -d -i -l -P -r -s pgdba
new role's password : pgdba
retype password : pgdba
password : postgres

localhost.localdomain:[/home/postgres]psql
Password: postgres
psql (9.0.1)
Type "help" for help.
postgres=# select * from pg_shadow;
 usename  | usesysid | usecreatedb | usesuper | usecatupd |               passwd                | valuntil | useconfig 
----------+----------+-------------+----------+-----------+-------------------------------------+----------+-----------
 postgres |       10 | t           | t        | t         | md53175bce1d3201d16594cebf9d7eb3f9d |          | 
 pgdba    |    16385 | t           | t        | t         | md53cd688326933adcdedd77097c95d131d |          | 
(2 rows)

postgres=# \q

localhost.localdomain:[/home/postgres]psql -U pgdba
Password for user pgdba: pgdba
FATAL:  database "pgdba" does not exist

psql: FATAL:  database "pgdba" does not exist
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See how the message is that *database* pgdba does not exist?

By default, PostgreSQL will connect to a database named after the current user (see [the psql docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html). Since you aren't specifying a database to connect to, it's trying to connect to a DB named `pgdba` - which doesn't exist.

Try:

```
psql -U pgdba postgres
```

to connect to the `postgres` database using role `pgdba`.

You may also need to examine `pg_hba.conf` (see [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) if you wish to tweak the authentication rules.

BTW, you are running an outdated PostgreSQL version with known bugs. Please update to 9.0.8, the latest patch release in the 9.0 series. You do not need to dump and reload your database or use `pg_upgrade` for this, it's a simple drop-in replacement. See the [release notes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/release.html) for all the fixes you're missing.

Also, rather than `SELECT`ing from `pg_shadow`, consider using psql's user information functions `\du` and `\dg`, which produce much better formatted and integrated information.